# Do not start apache service with svn webdav

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, webdav

When i try starting apache service with svn and webDav i get this error message:

```
Syntax error on line 120 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf:
Invalid command 'AuthUserFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

The lines 115 - 125:

```
<Location /svn>
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath /var/svn/teste
     SVNListParentPath On
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "myproject subversion repository"
     AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/senhas
     <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Require valid-user
     </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

I search the mod_auth and i can not find him. How fix this?

I use ubuntu and apache2

Comment: Please post lines 115 - 125 of the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the **authn_file** apache module enabled.

To do so on a Debian/Ubuntu server you would issue `a2enmod authn_file` and then restart apache.

Comment: When i do this, i get error message: "authn_file does not exist!"

Comment: What OS and apache version are you running?

Comment: Apache 2.2.17 and Ubuntu SMP

Comment: You should definitely be able to issue the "a2enmod authn_file" command without error then. Do you have authn_file.load in /etc/apache2/mods-available? Did you install apache from the repositories or is this a manual build? Oh, you need to do that command either as the root user or by prefixing sudo.